# JQuery. Prevent selecting time before current in TimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have i TimePicker component where I can set minimum date :

```
$wnd.$("#" + id).datetimepicker({
        minDate: new Date(2010, 11, 20, 8, 30),
```

But how to get current time (with minutes!) and put it into this component? (i want to set min date as current date with minutes). I try next:

```
var time = new Date().getTime(); //get current time in milliseconds
var date = new Date(time); // new time with milliseconds
$wnd.$("#" + id).datetimepicker({
        minDate: date,
```

But in TimePicker user constrained  only  with current date, not with current hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the it as `minDate:0`